# How can I still use the automation property of a table when adding a new row while locking the formulas in certain columns? (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

My team and I work on a table to enter other employees data. Some columns contain formulas and there is always someone that manages to mess-up the formula. Consequently, I would like to protect/lock the formulas within these columns. However, when using the protect sheet tool to lock the formulas, I cannot insert/delete new rows in the table nor automatically add a new row by inserting data in the last row of the table. Also, the filtering tool stops working as well.

Is there a way to counter this problem through VBA? If so, How should I procees (I'm a VBA beginner).

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

- ***Note:*** The provided snippet may not entirely resolve your issue, as users may alter the formula in various scenarios. Nevertheless, it serves as a starting point for your consideration.
- Assuming there are formuls on Col2 and Col4.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    With Target
        Dim c As Range
        Set c = Application.Intersect(Target, Me.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange)
        If c Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        If .Columns.Count = 1 And (.Column = 2 Or .Column = 4) Then
            If c.Address = .Address Then
                With Application
                    .EnableEvents = False
                    .Undo
                    .EnableEvents = True
                End With
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want a little more protection, you can try the below process to control the formulas. This method would prevent anyone from messing with the formulas because every time the column is touched, it resets the formula for the whole table column. It also keeps any other changes the user made to other columns. As a result, when new rows are added to the table object, the formula will already be there.

Stronger formula protection, but the downside is you can't edit the formula on the sheet. Every solution has trade-offs.

The `Worksheet_Change` event code would be added on the sheet in question via the VBA editor (alt + F11). In the VBA Editor, double click on the sheet with your data in the Project panel on the left. Then in the new window, select "Worksheet" from the first dropdown at the top and "Change" from the second dropdown. Copy and paste the insides of the code to your file. Make sure to save the file as .xlsm, for which Excel will remind you.

This code setup does require that your data is formatted as a table object in the Excel file, not just data on the page, and that the file is opened in your Excel desktop application. This will not work in Office 365 online, since you indicated the process has multiple users.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Dim myTbl as ListObject
    Set myTbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)

    '// If there is an intersection in the ranges
    If Application.Intersect(Target, myTbl.ListColumns("[Calc Column Header Name]").DataBodyRange)
       myTbl.ListColumns("[Calc Column Header Name]").DataBodyRange.Formula = "[Formula Text]"
    End If
    '// Repeat as necessary to cover all columns with formulas

End Sub
```